# What is the maximum of google docs api upload a file ??

Tags: google-docs-api

I have created a application via java-cilent-api to upload and download files in the Google Docs. after Doc up to 5GB,I try to upload a 4GB zip to Google docs and it complete it with no exception;however,the file is not appear in Google docs?? what is the maximum of the upload a file???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum file size in a [resumable upload request](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#creating_and_uploading_documents_and_files) is 10GiB. For simple requests (not using resumable), the maximum file size is 2MiB.

At the end of the upload request (either resumable or simple), you should get the newly inserted resource's metadata back from the API. The metadata includes an `alternate` link which points to the web version of the file. Try going to this URL and see if the file exists.